# Problem with navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, base-link, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi 
I'm using the navigation stack to move my robot. I defined the tf between /map and /odom and the tf between /odom and /base_link so my tf tree respects the ROS convention.
But when I launch move_base.launch I get this warning:

> **[ WARN] [1346331439.052407413]: Waiting on transform from /base_link
> to /map to become available before
> running costmap, tf error:**

How can I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42648/problem-with-navigation-stack/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can mean that you localization is not working. How did you define the transformation between /odom and /map? Are you running amcl localization and a robot? Or are you working in simulation?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-08-30**:
I'm working on a real robot and I'm running AMCL localization. The transformations should be defined in the right way because the TF display status is OK and also the tf tree is displayed in the correct way.